# add foreign key with on update cascade

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

Let's say, I have 2 tables

user

```
+----+--------+
| id | status |
+----+--------+
|  1 | A      |
|  2 | A      |
+----+--------+
```

article

```
+----+-----+--------+
| id | uid | status |
+----+-----+--------+
|  1 |   1 | A      |
|  2 |   2 | A      |
|  3 |   2 | A      |
|  4 |   2 | A      |
|  5 |   1 | A      |
|  6 |   2 | A      |
|  7 |   2 | A      |
|  8 |   1 | A      |
|  9 |   2 | A      |
| 10 |   2 | A      |
+----+-----+--------+
```

How can I add a foreign key that if I run this query:

```
UPDATE user SET status='B' WHERE id=1 OR id=2;
```

the result will be:

user

```
+----+--------+
| id | status |
+----+--------+
|  1 | B      |
|  2 | B      |
+----+--------+
```

article

```
+----+-----+--------+
| id | uid | status |
+----+-----+--------+
|  1 |   1 | B      |
|  2 |   2 | B      |
|  3 |   2 | B      |
|  4 |   2 | B      |
|  5 |   1 | B      |
|  6 |   2 | B      |
|  7 |   2 | B      |
|  8 |   1 | B      |
|  9 |   2 | B      |
| 10 |   2 | B      |
+----+-----+--------+
```

Or in other words, if I update column `user.status`, MySQL will automatically update column `article.status` with the respective value.

How can I create this foreign key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That job is not foreign key could finish. Use an update trigger, but for better Database compatibility, do this action on you code is preferred.

Trigger code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER SetArticleStatus AFTER UPDATE ON user 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
UPDATE `article` 
   SET status = NEW.status 
 WHERE uid = NEW.id
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your FOREIGN KEY is only `uid` and doesn't know about `status` the thing you want can't be accomplished using only foreign-keys. This looks like a good use-case for a on-update-trigger.